# Alterar coluna de boolean para integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou utilizando um banco de dados que tem um campo chamado: `status: boolean`, porém quero armazenar nela os valores do radio Button (0,1,2) então preciso mudar para `integer`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei:

```
ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS TYPE BOOLEAN USING (trim(STATUS)::integer);
ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS TYPEINTEGER;
```

Porém deu estes erros:

```
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.btrim(boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: ... TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS TYPE INTEGER USING (trim(STATU...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

ERROR:  column "status" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING status::integer".
```

Tenho como resolver isso sem precisar criar novamente a tabela?

Comment: Não, mude para smallint .

Comment: Só criando a table a de novo?

Comment: ou você pode criar um https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html , acho que no seu caso é melhor um Enum ... você pode fazer um [alter table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608570/2740371)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que sua tabela `OS` seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE OS
(
    ID INTEGER,
    STATUS BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 100, TRUE );
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 200, FALSE );
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 300, TRUE );
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 400, FALSE );
```

**1)** Cria-se uma coluna auxiliar na tabela com o tipo desejado:

```
ALTER TABLE OS ADD COLUMN STATUS_AUX SMALLINT;
```

**2)** Converte-se os dados pré-existentes na coluna original para a coluna auxiliar de forma adequada:

```
UPDATE OS SET STATUS_AUX = 0 WHERE STATUS = FALSE;
UPDATE OS SET STATUS_AUX = 2 WHERE STATUS = TRUE;
```

**3)** Exclui-se a coluna original:

```
ALTER TABLE OS DROP COLUMN STATUS;
```

**4)** Renomeia-se a coluna auxiliar para o nome da coluna original:

```
ALTER TABLE OS RENAME COLUMN STATUS_AUX TO STATUS;
```

**5)** Inclui-se uma `CONSTRAINT` de verificação na tabela `OS` para garantir a integridade dos dados do campo `STATUS` (0, 1 ou 2):

```
ALTER TABLE OS ADD CONSTRAINT chk_os_status CHECK ( STATUS = 0 OR STATUS = 1 OR STATUS = 2  );
```

**6)** Opcionalmente, o campo `STATUS` pode ser `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS SET NOT NULL;
```

Inserindo dados:

```
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 500, 0 );    -- OK!
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 600, 1 );    -- OK!
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 700, 2 );    -- OK!
```

Testando `CONSTRAINT`:

```
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 800, 3 );    -- ERRO! (CHECK CONSTRAINT)
```

Testando `NOT NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO OS ( ID, STATUS ) VALUES ( 900, NULL ); -- ERRO! (NOT NULL)
```

Funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ca657/6)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um [Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347716/2740371) e usar na sua tabela da seguinte forma.

```
CREATE TYPE StatusAceitacao AS ENUM ('Aceita', 'Finalizada', 'Fechada'); 

ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS TYPE StatusAceitacao USING CASE WHEN STATUS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Ou simplesmente mude para [smallint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html).

```
ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE OS ALTER COLUMN STATUS TYPE smallint USING CASE WHEN STATUS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

[Referencia 1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html);
[Referencia 2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: Lembrando que se a tabela `OS` já estiver populada, somente alterar o tipo da coluna `STATUS` de `BOOLEAN` para `SMALLINT` pode ser **fatal** para os dados já contidos na tabela. Certamente os dados serão convertidos por meio de um `CAST` implícito, fazendo que tudo que seja `TRUE` se torne `Finalizada` e tudo que seja `FALSE` se torne `Aceita`.

Comment: @Lacobus, certo bem lembrado... corrigi isso.

Comment: Sou um grande defensor da ideia de que instruções de definição de estrutura (`DDL`) não devem nunca alterar dados de forma *implícita*. É uma boa prática que isso sejá feito somente por instruções de manipulação de dados (`DML`) de forma *explícita*. Em muitos ambientes corporativos controlados, a gestão dos dados e da estrutura dos dados é feita de forma separada, e em tais ambientes, *scripts* assim não seriam aceitos pelos `DBAs`.

Comment: politicas e termos de usos não são mencionados na pergunta.

Comment: Mesmo assim, boas práticas sempre serão "boas".